# Multivar limit $\frac{6x-2y}{9x^2-y^2}$ by approach

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm resolving the limit of $\frac{6x-2y}{9x^2-y^2}$  when $(x,y)\to(1,3)$

We didn't study any special theorem, we did only approach.

I tried first the  changes $y=mx$ and $y=x^2$.

In $f(x,mx)$ ,operating I get that the $lim =\frac{6x-2mx}{9x^2-m^2x^2}$,dividing all by $x$.
$lim =\frac{6-2m}{9x-m^2x}$
Now,the frac didn't exist if the $m^2=1$ .Applying L'Hopital I get $\frac{0}{9-m^2}$
so the frac didn't exist if the $m^2=9$
So,when you reach that point, what thats mean? First I think that the limit is 0 in all cases except when $m^2=3$,but not make to much sense becouse before applying L'Hopital, the value of non-existence was  $m^2$=1.
In $f(x,x^2)$ , I get $lim =\frac{6x-2x^2}{9x^2-x^4}$ dividing by x I get
$lim =\frac{6-2x}{9x-x^3}$ then "replacing" I get that the $lim=1/2$

I know that the easy way is to do $\frac{2.(3x-y)}{(3x+y).(3x-y)}$ simplifying and get that the $lim=1/3$, so why when replacing $f(x,x^2)$ gives me $1/2$? and please can clarify a bit about what indicates when I do the steps to get $f(x,0)$,and I get a value for m that the frac didn't exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right answer is $\frac13$. Remember that $(x,y)\to(1,3)$.

The operations that you have tried, like $y=mx$ or $y=x^2$ in general can be applied only when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Comment: Yes you are right,the functions that I tried didn't approaches to the point $(1,3)$